# Copy support failed for -- Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: 14.04, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 with Ubuntu 14.04. I am getting a message like below :

[image]

Why this one is coming ? How can I stop it ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks @WillShakleford for your reply.  Here is some of my last few lines of IDE Log.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:\wamp\www\llsynckers
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FolderObj.createFolderImpl(FolderObj.java:240)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FolderObj$2.call(FolderObj.java:324)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FolderObj$2.call(FolderObj.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.FileBasedFileSystem.runAsInconsistent(FileBasedFileSystem.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.fileobjects.FolderObj.createFolder(FolderObj.java:327)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.createFolder(FileUtil.java:723)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.createFolder(FileUtil.java:480)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.LocalOperationFactory.doCopy(LocalOperationFactory.java:333)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.LocalOperationFactory.access$300(LocalOperationFactory.java:65)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.LocalOperationFactory$2.call(LocalOperationFactory.java:222)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.LocalOperationFactory$2.call(LocalOperationFactory.java:213)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.CopySupport$ProxyOperationFactory$ProxyHandler.callLocal(CopySupport.java:645)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.CopySupport$ProxyOperationFactory$ProxyHandler.call(CopySupport.java:619)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.CopySupport$ProxyOperationFactory$ProxyHandler.call(CopySupport.java:603)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.project.copysupport.CopySupport$3.run(CopySupport.java:162)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)`

Answer (score 0):

It could fail for any number of reasons directory doesn't exist, permissions, etc. Generally you should be able to find more specific information by looking at View -> IDE Log